# Is there any practice suggestion on how to use knockout.js framework (MVVM) to develop jQuery-plugin?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

After survey around the Internet, most MVVM tutorial, especially web client framework such as knockout.js focus on application level scenarios. But for my point of view, it'd be better to apply MVVM entirely from component-unit, to composite-component, then application. Do you have any ideas and/or experience to share?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question, maybe you could provide some concrete scenarios we could provide feedback on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Knockout Mvvm & View Models](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm_and_view_models)

> Model-View-View Model (MVVM) is a design pattern for building user
>   interfaces. It describes how you can keep a potentially sophisticated
>   UI simple by splitting it into three parts...

So by definition the pattern doesn't apply to components.  It is really intended to help with designing the entire UI.  I've been using this pattern for 24 months now and I'm completely sold.  For small projects, it's complete overkill.  But once project starts to get to a reasonable size it really helps.

I've been using knockout heavily for 4 months now and it has completely changed how I program web UI's.  Initially, it was for all of the MVVM benefits.  But I've found that using knockout has allowed me to write almost no (by comparison) jQuery event handlers.

Hope this answers your question.  If not, leave a comment with your concerns.

Comment: Of coz, I'm looking forward to an answer of YES. However, no more gurus provide other perspectives of opinions. Or, I've to think deeper into it.